# how to control the rotation of the scene using track ball control using three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I am constructing the building in 3D using three.js and webgl , i had placed the plane , sky , building on the plane , i had used TrackballControls to rotate the camera - it works perfect for zoom , pan but the plan rotates upside down , since i am constructing floor planner , i dont want to show the down side , I tried using OrbitControls and fixed rotation for this ,but the panning and zooming options are not flexible as TrackballControls 
Below are my code for TrackballControls

```
   `controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );  
    controls.userPan = true;
    controls.userPanSpeed = 0.0;        
    controls.userZoom  = true;
    controls.userZoomSpeed  = 2.0;      
    controls.userRotate  = true;
    controls.userRotateSpeed  = 1.0;
    controls.minDistance = 1.0; // how far can you zoom in
    controls.maxDistance = 1500.0; // how far can you zoom out      
    controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI *0.495;        
    controls.minPolarAngle = Math.PI/8;
    controls.rotation = Math.PI / 12;
    controls.minPolarAngle =  Math.PI *0.495;`
```

and for OrbitControls

```
   `controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );       
    controls.userPan = true;
    controls.userPanSpeed = 0.0;        
    controls.userZoom  = true;
    controls.userZoomSpeed  = 2.0;      
    controls.userRotate  = true;
    controls.userRotateSpeed  = 2.0;
    controls.minDistance = 1.0; // how far can you zoom in
    controls.maxDistance = 1500.0; // how far can you zoom out      
    controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI * 0.495;`
```

I feel TrackballControls is userfriendly , but need to fix the rotation alone , can any one guide me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to use `OrbitControls`. What is wrong with `OrbitControls` panning and zooming?

Comment: I tried using OrbitControls but the object or model i created rotates away from the center point and the zooming is also focused tot he center point , i have to zoom or pan where ever i place the mouse pointer

Comment: Both `OrbitControls` and `TrackballControls` zoom toward, and rotate around, `controls.target`. They both support panning. You can change the target like so: `controls.target.set( x, y, z )`.

Comment: Hi WestLangley i had used TrackballControls , and now i modified the Trackballcontrols.js - i hide the line `_this.object.up.applyQuaternion( quaternion );` - so that the rotation is controlled in east, west and noth side , now the plane rotates in the south side ( so that the underground position of the building is shown ) - i need to control that too - so that user should not roate to see the underground of the building - kindly guide me

Comment: Sorry, I can only answer questions about three.js. I can't help you write your code.